# Algorithms for computing pure strategy Nash equilibria

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, game-theory, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm looking through many sources, such as [this](https://people.csail.mit.edu/costis/simplified.pdf) one that mention algorithms, and time complexity of finding *mixed* strategy Nash equilibria.

But is there any algorithm for finding pure strategy Nash equilibria? This algorithm does not need to be fast (as this problem is in NP, as far as I have read).

The trivial solution would be to check every single strategy profile, but this would be time complexity $O(\prod^{N}_{i=1} n_i)$, where N is the number of players, and n is an array containing how many pure strategies each player has

Comment: Are you looking to find every pure strategy Nash equilibrium or only one? If so is there any requirement to which one, or can it be any?

Comment: @LoicStoic I think it depends on what the current methods are— I’m really just looking to see what has been done with this problem. If an existing algorithm only outputs one, can you direct me to the algorithm specification?

Comment: @wavosa you can interpret a pure strategy as a mixed strategy where one option is chosen 100% of the time.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I agree. But I would like to only find the pure strategy equilibria. 1. There could be algorithms faster for just pure strategy Nash equilibria. 2. There may be $O(2^N)$ mixed Nash equilibria . Searching through them is $O(2^N)$. That is why I ask this question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154991/755

Answer (score 1):

I googled this topic and found this paper: ["Pure Nash Equilibria: Hard and Easy Games"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/846241.846269), Gottlob et al, 2005 ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2152.pdf))

> While pure strategies are conceptually simpler than mixed strategies, the associated computational problems appear to be harder. In fact, we show that even if severe restrictions are imposed on the set of allowed strategies, determining whether a game has a pure Nash or Pareto Equilibrium is NP-complete, while deciding whether a game has a strong Nash equilibrium is even Σ2
> -complete.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if anything is known about solving games that are already *known* to have pure strategy Nash equilibria. Like a promise problem.

Comment: I would guess that it doesn't always help: my guess is that there exists some class of games where we know they have pure Nash equilibria, but where it's still this hard to find them. However, the paper (I updated it with an arxiv link) describes a bunch of classes of games where pure Nash equilibria are efficiently solvable.